# Terms query in java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I'm trying to add terms in the should clause of ES query in java spring boot. I need it to look like this:

```
"should": [
    {
      "terms": {
        "segment_status.nse_status": [
          2,
          3
        ],
        "boost": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "terms": {
        "segment_status.pml_status": [
          2,
          3
        ],
        "boost": 1
      }
    }
  ]
```

I'm able to add only one terms condition for each should clause, but I need to append multiple terms in the same should clause. My code currently:

```
TermsQueryBuilder termsQuery = termsQuery(SEGMENT_STATUS + DOT + "bse_status", failedUserStatues);
BoolQueryBuilder includeCriteria = boolQuery();
includeCriteria.should(termsQuery);
NestedQueryBuilder nestedQueryForCriteria = nestedQuery(SEGMENT_STATUS, includeCriteria, ScoreMode.Avg);
searchQuery.must(nestedQueryForCriteria);
```

I'm using spring boot and ES version 6.4

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked as expected.
Iterate using a loop and create a terms query in each iteration and call should(termsQuery) in each iteration.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

We can add multiple terms in single should clause by using below code

```
BoolQueryBuilder query = boolQuery()
            .should(termQuery("segment_status.nse_status", new int[]{2,3}).boost(1f))
            .should(termQuery("segment_status.pml_status", new int[]{2,3}).boost(1f));
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
TermsQueryBuilder nseStatusQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.termsQuery("segment_status.nse_status", 2, 3);
TermsQueryBuilder pmlStatusQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.termsQuery("segment_status.pml_status", 2, 3);

sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(nseStatusQueryBuilder).should(pmlStatusQueryBuilder));
elasticsearchTemplate.search(new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withSource(sourceBuilder).build(), YourDocument.class);
```

Here we created two terms query using `TermsQueryBuilder` and then using `boolQuery` and should method attached those query to should.

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple terms within the same "should" clause, you can modify your code to use a "bool" query with the "should" clause. Each "should" clause within the "bool" query can contain multiple "terms" conditions.

Here's an example of how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
        TermsQueryBuilder termsQuery1=termsQuery(SEGMENT_STATUS+DOT+"nse_status",failedUserStatues);
    TermsQueryBuilder termsQuery2=termsQuery(SEGMENT_STATUS+DOT+"pml_status",failedUserStatues);

    BoolQueryBuilder includeCriteria=boolQuery();
    includeCriteria.should(termsQuery1);
    includeCriteria.should(termsQuery2);

    NestedQueryBuilder nestedQueryForCriteria=nestedQuery(SEGMENT_STATUS,includeCriteria,ScoreMode.Avg);
    searchQuery.must(nestedQueryForCriteria);
```